# Lucene as a high-volume cache?

Tags: java, caching, lucene, batch-processing

I work with a system where we do a lot of batch processing.  We have caches that are pre-loaded to help with data lookup performance.  There are scenarios however where I cannot cache the entire dataset into memory.  Up to this point, I've been reverting to running a query to lookup the data which kills performance.  In an attempt to resolve, I've added a hybrid cache where I use a HashMap up to a threshold and then I spill over to a Lucene index (local file system).  This is a definite improvement over running the query (anywhere from 6 to 10 times faster than the database query).  However, I was hoping for a little better and was wondering if there are better alternatives for this kind of thing.  I'm using a single String as my key and am caching Java objects.  I'd like to stick with a Java library to not complicate my deployment.  (I'd like to avoid a separate server process.)  I was wondering if anyone else was using Lucene for this purpose.  Are there better alternatives for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you are using a single string as key and don't need to run queries in the data stored, you could use Google's LevelDB. It has good performance and does low memory usage. Check this: http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/

Answer (score 1):

There are several cache libraries available that should be able to handle your situation by writing cache entries to disk if a certain threshold is reached. A good strategy is to write the entries to disk that are leased accessed. There are also caches out there that distribute the cache entries over a cluster, keeping everything in memory.

A cache solution that I use often is Infinispan: http://www.jboss.org/infinispan

It is fast, easy to use, scalable and can certainly handle your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[EhCache](http://ehcache.org)! seems to be a good fit for what I need.  It performs much better than Lucene for this single key lookup.  It supports disk overflow and is simple to use.